# Does the wheel on the wall do anything at all?

Tags: the-stanley-parable-2011

Briefly before the suicide ending, a red handle is provided to the player. He can turn it 90 degrees.

I turned it in my playthrough, but I was left wondering, does it actually do anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge, it doesn't.  As you proceed down the hall, you'll notice other random objects from elsewhere in the game.

The obvious conclusion is that is the narrator's area (the original narrator, not the new one), and that it also represents the futility of your actions in the game (much like everything else in the game).

However, it appears to be left intentionally vague.